# Remove capture groups from a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex 'simple' that I'd like to use as a building block for another regex 'complex'. The trouble is, the capture groups in 'simple' are interfering with 'complex'. These low level capture groups are details I don't to care about. I'd love to remove them before the regex is consumed.

The question is: how?

Put another way, in code, this isn't working well:

```
simple = /(a)bc/
complex = /(#{simple}) - (#{simple})/
complex.match("abc - abc").captures # => ["abc", "a", "abc", "a"]
// when I need ["abc","abc"]
```

I'd much rather write:

```
simple = /(a)bc/
complex = /(#{simple.without_capture}) - (#{simple.without_capture})/
complex.match("abc - abc").captures # => ["abc", "abc"]
```

I'm a stuck on how to do this, but I'm betting it's been done before. The implementation of `Regex#without_capture` would need to of course account for non-capturing groups, look ahead/behind, etc. So simply removing all the () isn't enough. Also, finding the matching ) for capture groups seems a little challenging.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention. I don't want to manually create two versions of simple (a capturing and non-capturing). In my actual case it would be impractical to maintain both versions. It'd be much better to be able to toggle the capturing dynamically.

Comment: So you have an arbitrary pile of arbitrary regular expressions combined (in arbitrary ways) to build a final regex. Then you only want the outermost capture groups but you don't want to change any of the component regexes?

Comment: @muistooshort Yep, you got it.

Comment: Too bad you're not on .NET - or can you use IronRuby? .NET regexes support the `(?n)` mode modifier which makes all capturing groups non-capturing (and `(?-n)` turns them back on).

Comment: You could use named capturing groups, and then just pull the named groups out.

Comment: I don't know if this would produce the result you're looking for, but what about modifying captures method so if you do:`complex.match("abc - abc").captures(simple)` it subtracts the captures from simple

Comment: @JacobEggers That method works for this simple scenario, but means I can only used named captures in the 'final' regex. When composing sub-regexps I'd rather not be worried about those details. Looking for something more flexible.

Comment: @derp that's an interesting idea. It's downside is that I need to know all the sub expressions used in the final expression so I can subtract them out. That makes sense for 1 level hierarchies (as in my example) but breaks down if we go any deeper.

Comment: @TheDeeno but if the one passed is calculated normally it should contain the sub captures or not?, if I have `basic > simple > complex`, since `simple`contains those from basic, `complex - simple` should do it, you'd only have to add more than one if let's say complex uses two or more other regexp at the same time.

Comment: @derp that's a good point. In that case your method has the advantage of being far less magical. Still, one would need to know the sub-expressions at match time, which a consumer may not know or care to know. True?

Comment: @TheDeeno that's true, using this approach I guess the other possibility would be defining a hierarchy like `complex.child = simple` right after you create the regexp and then use a custom method directly over complex like `complex.captures_mod("abc - abc")` which would check for `@child.nil?` and do it's thing... again this means the consumer would have to know to call `captures_mod` instead of `match().captures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is harder than I thought. Rather than spin more wheels if I change one requirement everything seems easy. Instead of trying to replace any capture group, replace only named capture groups.

Thanks @JustinMorgan and @TimPietzcker for getting me this far.

This is what I've come up with:

```
class Regexp
  # replaces all named capture groups with non-capturing groups
  # in other words, it replaces all (?<*>...) with (?:...)
  def without_named_captures
      named_captures = %r{\(\?<[^>]+>}
      pattern = self.source.gsub(named_captures, "(?:")
      Regexp.new(pattern)
  end
end
```

Which passes this spec:

```
describe "Regexp Extensions" do
  describe "#without_named_captures" do
    it "should replace named captures with non-captures" do
      p1 = /(?<a>.*) - (?<b>.*)/
      p2 = p1.without_named_captures

      p2.should == /(?:.*) - (?:.*)/

      # sanity check
      p1.match('abc - def').should have_exactly(3).items
      p2.match('abc - def').should have_exactly(1).items
    end
  end
end
```

Dealing with recursion, escaping, and all the other junk, just goes away when the token is more complex than a single '('. If I use named captures everywhere, I can use this method. If I don't, well things behave normally.

It's late, so I don't know if I'm missing anything, but I think this'll work.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the best way to do this would be to create two versions of "simple", but since you indicated you don't want to do that, you could try running "simple" through this regex:

```
/\((?!\?)/
```

...and replacing whatever matches that with `(?:`. However, I want to emphasize that trying to process regex with regex makes me very nervous. I can't guarantee the above pattern won't produce false positives, depending on what you feed into it.

I know it won't properly handle an escaped open-parenthesis (that is, `\(` meant to be interpreted as a literal `(` character). You can mitigate that by using `/(^|[^\\])\((?!\?)/` instead, and replacing it with `$1(?:`, but that will produce false *negatives* if the backslash itself is escaped (i.e. `\\(` meant to be interpreted as a literal backslash and the start of a group).

The real solution to this would be something like `/(?<!(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*\\)\((?!\?)/` to check for an odd-numbered string of backslashes, but since Ruby doesn't support lookbehinds, I'd say go with `/(^|[^\\])\((?!\?)/` or whatever seems most sane to you.

Comment: aha! I think this is on the right track. I was trying to remove the groups, but switching them to non-capture seems like a _much_ better option. I'll check this out and report back.

Comment: Remember that character classes like `[()]` would also be modified by this. I'm pretty sure that you'd need a regex parser to be able to detect capturing quotes correctly.

Comment: @Tim - Excellent point. I knew there would be something out there this wouldn't catch.

Comment: @JustinMorgan FYI, ruby 1.9 supports look-behind. Still, the character class issue Tim brought up makes this pretty hard. I don't think a robust solution is possible this way. Do you agree? Or can you think of some way to avoid matching parans in char classes?

Comment: Well, you could do something like `/(?<!(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*(\\|\[[^\]]*))\((?!\?)/` if lookbehinds are supported. Off the top of my head, I don't see any holes in that. However, if that made your brain hurt as much as mine, you might want to go with the regex parser idea.

Comment: @JustinMorgan turns out I can do lookbehinds _only_ if the top level sub-expressions are of a fixed length. Pretty weak. Without variable length lookbehinds testing for escaping is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know in which cases this would fail but it's my try:

```
class MatchData
    alias_method :captures_old, :captures
    def captures(other = false)
        unless other
            self.captures_old
        else
            self.captures_old - other.match(self.to_s).captures_old
        end
    end
end

#example
basic = /(a)/
simple = /#{basic}b(c)/
complex = /(#{simple}) - (#{simple})/

#usual behavior
p basic.match("abc - abc").captures
p simple.match("abc - abc").captures
p complex.match("abc - abc").captures
#removes those from simple which also contain those from basic
p complex.match("abc - abc").captures(simple)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, however, I've written a refinement for a parser project with many expressions with capture groups for scanning which need identical non-capturing counterparts for splitting.

```
refine Regexp do
  def decapture
    Regexp.new(to_s.gsub(/\(\?<\w+>|(?<![^\\]\\)\((?!\?)/, '(?:'))
  end
end
```

It works for capture groups as well as named capture groups, honors expression options, special groups and literal backslash/parenthesis couples. Here are the tests (Ruby 2.5):

```
describe :decapture do
  it "should replace capture groups with non-capture groups" do
    /(foo) baz (bar)/.decapture.must_equal /(?-mix:(?:foo) baz (?:bar))/
    /(foo) baz (bar)/i.decapture.must_equal /(?i-mx:(?:foo) baz (?:bar))/
  end

  it "should replace named capture groups with non-capture groups" do
    /(?<a>foo) baz (?<b>bar)/.decapture.must_equal /(?-mix:(?:foo) baz (?:bar))/
    /(?<a>foo) baz (?<b>bar)/i.decapture.must_equal /(?i-mx:(?:foo) baz (?:bar))/
  end

  it "should not replace special groups" do
    /(?:foo) (?<=baz) bar/.decapture.must_equal /(?-mix:(?:foo) (?<=baz) bar)/
  end

  it "should not replace literal round brackets" do
    /\(foo\)/.decapture.must_equal /(?-mix:\(foo\))/
  end

  it "should replace literal backslash followed by literal round brackets" do
    /\\(foo\\)/.decapture.must_equal /(?-mix:\\(?:foo\\))/
  end
end
```

Comment: This fails for `/\\\(10\)/` and also `/[(]/`

Answer (score 0):

You can switch all the capture groups in a particular regex to non-capture.
I don't really know Ruby regex flavor very well, buy you should get the jist
with this Perl example. I wote a superset regex to graphically annotate capture
buffers within a regex.

This is the light version, and generalized for common regex notation.
It generally does a global replacement with a call-back, testing a capt buffer
to determine which type of match  we have.

Sorry if this is slightly complex.

**Edit** Note that this was originally used as an annotation regex using a global
search and no replacement. Coverting to non-capture groups could undermine the
original regexs' intent when it comes to back references to non-named capture groups.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#
 my $rxgroup = qr/
    (?:
        (?<!\\)   # Not an escape behind us

        ( (?:\\.)* )  ## CaptGRP 1 - 0 or more "escape + any char"

        ( ## CaptGRP 2

             # Exclude character class'
              \[
                 \]?
                 (?: \\.| \[:[a-z]*:\] | [^\]\n] )*
                 \n?
                 (?: \\.| \[:[a-z]*:\] | [^\]] )*
              \]
           |
             (?# Exclude extended comments )
               \(\?\# [^)]* \)
           |
             # Exclude free comments
              \# [^\n]*

           |
             # Start of a literal capture group
             ( \(  )      ## CaptGRP 3
              (?:
                  (?!\?)    # unnamed: not a ? in front of us

                ## block for annotation only  
                ##  |           # or (Perl 5.10 and above)
                ##              # named: a ?<name> or ?'name' is ok
                ##    (?= \?[<'][^\W\d][\w]*['>] )
              )
        )
     )
  /x;

#
 my @samples = (

  qr/ \(\$th(\\(?:.) [(] \\\\(.\)\\\(.)(i(s))\t(i(s)) ] )/x,
  qr/
     \(\$th(\\(?:.) [(]
     (?# Extended lines
         of comment
     )
     \\\\(.\)\\\(.)(i(s))\t(i(s)) ] )
    /x,
  $rxgroup
 );

#
 for (@samples)
 {
    print "\n\n", '='x20, "\nold: \n\n$_\n\n", '-'x10, "\n";
    s/$rxgroup/ defined $3 ? "$1(?:" : "$1$2" /eg;
    print "new: \n\n$_\n";
 }
```

Output:

```
====================
old:

(?x-ism: \(\$th(\\(?:.) [(] \\\\(.\)\\\(.)(i(s))\t(i(s)) ] ))

----------
new:

(?x-ism: \(\$th(?:\\(?:.) [(] \\\\(?:.\)\\\(.)(?:i(?:s))\t(?:i(?:s)) ] ))


====================
old:

(?x-ism:
     \(\$th(\\(?:.) [(]
     (?# Extended lines
         of comment
     )
     \\\\(.\)\\\(.)(i(s))\t(i(s)) ] )
    )

----------
new:

(?x-ism:
     \(\$th(?:\\(?:.) [(]
     (?# Extended lines
         of comment
     )
     \\\\(?:.\)\\\(.)(?:i(?:s))\t(?:i(?:s)) ] )
    )


====================
old:

(?x-ism:
    (?:
        (?<!\\)   # Not an escape behind us

        ( (?:\\.)* )  ## CaptGRP 1 - 0 or more "escape + any char"

        ( ## CaptGRP 2

             # Exclude character class'
              \[
                 \]?
                 (?: \\.| \[:[a-z]*:\] | [^\]\n] )*
                 \n?
                 (?: \\.| \[:[a-z]*:\] | [^\]] )*
              \]
           |
             (?# Exclude extended comments )
               \(\?\# [^)]* \)
           |
             # Exclude free comments
              \# [^\n]*

           |
             # Start of a literal capture group
             ( \(  )      ## CaptGRP 3
              (?:
                  (?!\?)    # unnamed: not a ? in front of us

                ## block for annotation only
                ##  |           # or (Perl 5.10 and above)
                ##              # named: a ?<name> or ?'name' is ok
                ##    (?= \?[<'][^\W\d][\w]*['>] )
              )
        )
     )
  )

----------
new:

(?x-ism:
    (?:
        (?<!\\)   # Not an escape behind us

        (?: (?:\\.)* )  ## CaptGRP 1 - 0 or more "escape + any char"

        (?: ## CaptGRP 2

             # Exclude character class'
              \[
                 \]?
                 (?: \\.| \[:[a-z]*:\] | [^\]\n] )*
                 \n?
                 (?: \\.| \[:[a-z]*:\] | [^\]] )*
              \]
           |
             (?# Exclude extended comments )
               \(\?\# [^)]* \)
           |
             # Exclude free comments
              \# [^\n]*

           |
             # Start of a literal capture group
             (?: \(  )      ## CaptGRP 3
              (?:
                  (?!\?)    # unnamed: not a ? in front of us

                ## block for annotation only
                ##  |           # or (Perl 5.10 and above)
                ##              # named: a ?<name> or ?'name' is ok
                ##    (?= \?[<'][^\W\d][\w]*['>] )
              )
        )
     )
  )
```